# How to enable/disable touchesMoved, touchesEnded and Swipe Gestures

Tags: swift, swift2, tvos, touchesmoved, touchesended

I am working on a game where I need `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` but after the stage is completed, I want to DISABLE `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` and enable **only** `SWIPE GESTURES`.

So how can I achieve this?

**When the game is being played**: I want swipe gestures to be disabled and `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` should be enabled.

**When the game is completed**: I want `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` to be disabled And swipe gestures to be enabled.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to disable touch return false in below method.

```
 func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```